# Inject interface implementation with CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, inject

I can't get a very simple point on CDI!

I have these classes in my application:

```
public class CarrelloController extends AbstractController {

    @Inject CarrelloService carrelloService;

    ...
}


@Stateless
public class CarrelloService implements CarrelloDataProvider {
   ...
}

public interface CarrelloDataProvider {
    public Oggetto getSomething(String foo);
}
```

However, I am getting the following error, after deploying:

> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
>   Unsatisfied dependencies for type CarrelloService with qualifiers
>   @Default   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Default
>   it.footballove.web.controller.CarrelloController.carrelloService   at
>   it.footballove.web.controller.CarrelloController.carrelloService(CarrelloController.java:0)
>
> at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception 0 :

I get that only using an interface. Abstract class instead makes no problem!

Why?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with _I get that only using an interface. Abstract class instead makes no problem!_. The code you posted show that the type of the injection point is the class `CarrelloService` and not its interface `CarrelloDataProvider`. Why are you doing so?

Comment: Because in that case I know I need that specific concrete implementation.
If I define CarrelloDataProvider as an abstract class and make the service extend it, I get no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way that EJBs work with CDI. The CDI [bean types of an EJB](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#session_bean_types) are given by the business interface of the EJB, not by the implementation class. The business interface may be explicitly declared with a `@Local` annotation.

In your case, the business interface defaults to the one and only declared interface `CarelloDataProvider`. So there really is no CDI bean of type `CarelloService`.

Suggestion:

Rename your EJB class to `CarelloServiceImpl` and factor out an interface `CarelloService` containing the extra methods you need in `CarelloController`.

```
@Stateless
public class CarelloServiceImpl implements CarelloService {
}

public interface CarelloService extends CarelloDataProvider {
}
```

Or just reconsider your design - usually, when you need to access an implementation method not contained in an interface, this is a symptom of mismatched abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

i've hit the same problem, following scenario:

```
public interface Importer() { ..... }
```

with following structure:

```
public abstract class DefaultImporter implements Importer { // some default methods }
```

and finally the implementation to use for injetion:

```
public class DefaultFileImporter extends DefaultImporter implements Serializable { ...}
```

this didn't work and the WELD exception state above has been thrown. I've tried to annonate the classes with @Named, @Qualifier, @Default... but non has worked.

In order to make the injection work with an abstract class, it is required to implement explicitly the interface in the service bean:

```
public class DefaultFileImporter extends DefaultImporter implements Importer, Serializable { ...}
```

Simple said: implement explicit the interface you want to injection into the implementation (in addition to the abstract class).